# Animation glitching in Eevee render

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

I'm having this weird glitch in the animation when it's rendered by Eevee.

Here's the render:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQp_8KcGCjo

Notice how the animation of the model glitches and rotates randomly at certain frames.

I've picked frame 3 to better visualize the issue.

Here's an Eevee render of frame 3:
[image]

And a Cycles render of the same frame (issue is not presenting):
[image]

I've tried to set the sampling number to a higher value without success.
After many renders and tweaks, I believe it's related to the motion blur, however, I can't figure what's causing it. Tried to add more steps to motion blur but the issue remains.

Any idea of how I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, how is your object position keyframed ? These glitches can come from objects that move quite far from one frame to the other, throwing off the motion blur algorithm

Comment: The model itself doesn't move in a axis, it remains on place while the running animation is played - the fast moving part is actualy the scenario, which is an array of a cube.There are no objects that move very far from one frame to the other.

Comment: Got an idea... maybe it's related to the cyclic motion I made using nonlinear animation? Even though it doesn't show the bug in the viewport (model motion plays without random rotation issues).

Comment: Hard to tell without the settings in front of me ^^ But it seems smart to dig in this direction. There might be optimisations in the viewport that prevent the glitch to appear